# How to know elastic search installed version from kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Currently I am getting these alerts:

> Upgrade Required Your version of Elasticsearch is too old. Kibana requires Elasticsearch 0.90.9 or above.

Can someone tell me if there is a way I can find the exact installed version of ELS?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

from the Chrome Rest client make a GET request or 
`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'` in console

rest client: **http://localhost:9200**

```
{
    "name": "node",
    "cluster_name": "elasticsearch-cluster",
    "version": {
        "number": "2.3.4",
        "build_hash": "dcxbgvzdfbbhfxbhx",
        "build_timestamp": "2016-06-30T11:24:31Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "5.5.0"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

where number field denotes the `elasticsearch` version. Here `elasticsearch` version is 2.3.4

Comment: if you do find the number here as a different than the one installed and probably wondering what I have done wrong. Then there is a good chance that there are two version of `elastic` are running on your host.

Comment: ElasticSearch 1.4.5 just returns `{"OK":{}}`. I could get the version by doing `curl localhost:9200/_nodes`.

Answer (score 86):

I would like to add which isn't mentioned in above answers.

From your kibana's dev console, hit following command:

```
GET /
```

This is similar to accessing `localhost:9200` from browser.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: This really helped me, with elasticsearch 6, when my browser didn't have access to a remote ES server's port 9200 but it did have access to a suitable kibana installation.

Answer (score 15):

You can check version of ElasticSearch by the following command. It returns some other information also:

**curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'**

```
{
  "name" : "Forgotten One",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "2.3.4",
    "build_hash" : "e455fd0c13dceca8dbbdbb1665d068ae55dabe3f",
    "build_timestamp" : "2016-06-30T11:24:31Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "5.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Here you can see the version number: 2.3.4

Typically Kibana is installed in **/opt/logstash/bin/kibana** . So you can get the kibana version as follows

## `/opt/kibana/bin/kibana --version`

Comment: Two things: you don't need `-X GET`, this is the default, and please don't stick values to arguments in life, as unexperienced people would think that `èGET` is an actual switch...

2. Please don't listen to those people in other places who will tell you to do `elasticsearch --version`, this may fail with memory error.

Answer (score 13):

navigate to the folder where you have installed your **kibana**
if you have used yum to install **kibana** it will be placed in following location by default

```
/usr/share/kibana
```

then use the following command

```
bin/kibana --version
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Dev Tools console in Kibana to obtain version information about Elasticsearch.

You click "Dev Tools" to navigate into console.

In the Dev Tools Console, you do a below query

```
GET /
```

You will see version and number like below with other details also.

```
{
  "version" : {
      "number" : "6.5.1",
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To check Version of Your Running Kibana,Try this:

Step1. Start your Kibana Service.

Step2.  Open Browser and Type below line,

```
    localhost:5601
```

Step3.  Go to settings->About

```
  You can See Version of Your Running kibana.
```

Comment: in my Kibana dashboard, there is no option as Settings. I can see Discover,Visualize,Dashboard,Timelion,Dev Tools,Management. That's all. I am running Kibana in a remote server but I guess that's not relevant here.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it on `Ubuntu 18.0.4`

```
sudo /usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana --version
```

Answer (score 4):

You can Try this,
     After starting Service of elasticsearch Type below line in your        browser.

```
         localhost:9200

     It will give Output Something like that,

          {
           "status" : 200,
           "name" : "Hypnotia",
           "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
           "version" : {
           "number" : "1.7.1",
           "build_hash" : "b88f43fc40b0bcd7f173a1f9ee2e97816de80b19",
           "build_timestamp" : "2015-07-29T09:54:16Z",
           "build_snapshot" : false,
            "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
                  },
            "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
                  }
```

Comment: i am using elastic search engine which is installed on local host.

Comment: my point is that due to version incompatibility i am unable to see that data in K3 GUI.

Comment: can you please tell me your ElasticSearch version.??   Because,Kibana 3 does not support Elasticsearch versions greater than 1.7.
            This is mentioned in the kibana 3 documentation(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/3.0/_introduction.html) but not in the release notes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed x-pack to secure elasticseach, the request should contains the valid credential details.

```
curl -XGET -u "elastic:passwordForElasticUser" 'localhost:9200'
```

Infact, if the security enabled all the subsequent requests should follow the same pattern (inline credentials should be provided).

Answer (score 4):

If you are logged into your Kibana, you can click on the `Management` tab and that will show your Kibana version. Alternatively, you can click on the small tube-like  icon [image] and that will show the version number.

Comment: This will show the _Kibana_ version but to find the _Elasticsearch_ version you should run `GET /` in the Kibana 'Dev Tools' console as per the answer from @ms_27

Answer (score 3):

From Kibana host, a request to http://localhost:9200/ will not be answered, unless ElasticSearch is also running on the same node.  Kibana listens on port 5601 not 9200.

In most cases, except for DEV, ElasticSearch will not be on the same node as Kibana, for a number of reasons.
Therefore, to get information about your ElasticSearch from Kibana, you should select the "Dev Tools" tab on the left and in the console issue the command: **GET /**

Answer (score 3):

If you looking for version in kibana ui
[image: Version kibana UI]